# Automating Windows applications hosted on Citrix, using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, citrix

I'm trying to automate a process wherein the user follows the method below to do his work.

1. Login to a portal with username and password through google chrome.
2. After login the page shows many icons(some are applications and some are folders). The user clicks on one of the folder icons.
3. The icon opens a Citrix folder on the local computer.
4. The user opens one of the files present in the folder, performs some manual changes and then saves and closes the file.

I have been able to reach until Step 3 where the folder opens up (using Selenium), however, I can't seem to figure out a way to pass key strokes to the folder (which is active when it opens). I even tried to find out the process id of the folder, but it appears that Citrix processes do not have `process_id` or may be they do not share it with Windows.

As per the following website, it appears that Selenium can't handle Citrix. But this got me thinking that there must be some other way to handle Citrix windows through Python.

[LINK HERE](https://www.leapwork.com/blog/citrix-automation-using-selenium-is-it-possible)

At this point, I don't know which direction I should be headed into.

Suggestions and ideas are appreciated!

Comment: What about using a script on the server (Autoit, Python, Powershell) that does the next steps and you only start that script on the server. Locally all should work as expected.